# What is Hosted Content Package in the Application Loader?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to enable In App Purchase for my an application. The type of purchase is **Non-Consumable** and I mark Host Content with Apple. When I want to host content with Apple I need to provide **Hosted Content Package**. I can not find more information what should be inside this content package. Except that it should be not bigger than 2GB and extension should be .pkg.

***How I could create Content Package for it? What should be inside it?***

**How I can create an In-App purchase content package in Xcode (with a .pkg file extension)?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To create In-App Purchase content package: **File -> New -> Project... -> Other (iOS) -> In-App Purchase Content**. New project will be created.

Put data to this project and choose: **Product -> Archive**. When archive is done choose **Distribute...**.

And you are done.

Very detailed explanation is written here: [In-App Purchase example](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Introduction_to_iOS_6/Changes_to_StoreKit)

Comment: I uploaded a package but status is still "Waiting for Upload". Will it take some time before realizing the package is there (because it is)?

Comment: Ok it took about 10-15 minutes and then the package was acknowledged by Apple's system.

Comment: Is this still the case? Even with the ability to create the IAP through iTunes Connect, I have to do it through Xcode too?

Comment: @DanLeveille Yes you need. You need todo it on both: iTunes Connect and throw Xcode.

Comment: @Ramis may I ask you what types of file could be accepted as In-App Purchase Content, I have sent an excel file containing the products ids and the title of the ebooks I will be selling on the app, along with their prices and I was able to upload it but on testing the product ids are not recognized on (productRequest).