# Application Loader Nightmare

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app

What kind of file should I drag to this window on Application Loader?

ZIP files are accepted but will give an error if you try to upload. Docs say it must be a .pkg file but Xcode just generates .xacrchive that cannot be dragged here and apple do not explain how to generate this pkg.

So? ....

[image]

Comment: I'm not actually sure, but I think you just need to `distribute` the archive you've made to create the .pkg file

Comment: Yes, here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598429/what-is-hosted-content-package-in-the-application-loader

Comment: Thanks! Make this comment an answer and I will accept it. Do you know if there is a way to generate this pkg by command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distribute the the archive. Here's a similar questions: [What is Hosted Content Package in the Application Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598429/what-is-hosted-content-package-in-the-application-loader)

Comment: thanks. I am now searching for a way to automate that creation... :D

Comment: I'm curious too. I'll let you know if I find anything.