# Unable to Validate Hosted Content Package in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to enable In App Purchase for my an application. I'm using Non-Consumable purchase type and I chose hosted content.
I followed the instructions in [What is Hosted Content Package in the Application Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598429/what-is-hosted-content-package-in-the-application-loader/13793299#13793299) for creating the .pkg file for IAP: File -> New -> Project... -> Other (iOS) -> In-App Purchase Content -> copied content into project then, Product -> Archive. When I clicked the "Validate..." button and entered my credentials, I got a strange error "Unable to process lookupSoftwareApplicationsWithHostedContent request at this time due to a general error" and all I can do is click OK. 
It does not get to the screen where it shows drop downs for the application and in-app purchase content, as in http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases.
I did what some postings suggested, such as restarting the Mac and/or Xcode, but that didn't help. I wonder if there's any specific setting on iTunes Connect that is causing this strange error.

Comment: Perhaps it's just ITC being ITC.  It's never been perfect, you know.  File a bug report.

Comment: Thanks. I sent an e-mail to them and they suggested that I developer reject my app because it was in "Waiting for Upload" status (and it's back to that status now) then associate my IAP with my app, which I did, but all of a sudden, all my IAPs turned into "Waiting for Review" status and each has a "PENDING" next to it.

Comment: Exactly.  IApps aren't  just automatically approved, they go through a process, just like applications.

Comment: What's really confusing is that Apple mentions in their documentation that "If you enable content hosting, you must upload your content before you submit it to Apple for review." First of all, if I edit my IAP entries, they don't show me the option of content hosting. Second, if I'm expected to upload my content before I submit for review and I can't upload that content because I'm unable to create the .pkg file due to that error then I'm in limbo..

Comment: All right. This is really strange.. I rejected the app as per the instructions given to me by Apple support and then I incremented its version as recommended in the docos. Since I couldn't upload the artifacts for the IAPs that I had, I deleted them all and was planning to create new ones from scratch (with different Product ID, also as required by the docos). However, when I try to create a new IAP now under the "Manage In-App Purchases" button, I don't see the "Hosting Content with Apple" section. What's going on? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I solved this problem!! It turns out I had to request an amendment in the contracts and submit it!! but now I'm facing yet another problem (this is frustrating).. When validating the Xcode .pkg for the IAP content, it complained about m4a audio files that I have in the package for sound. The strange thing is that it says: "The archive for In-App Purchase ... is invalid. The package contains an executable at 'Contents/xyz.m4a'."

Comment: @JoeMujarreb Hey .. how did you got rid of this error ? Even today I got this error number of time and not able to host the content. This is really rubbish, lack of doc. ;(